# How to generate selections for a drop down menu with row/record data from a database that will prefill a form when selected?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out a way to pre fill a form with data with past form information submitted in the past.

I have a form and a database.  In my form I have a input named `email` that holds the pre-loaded default value of logged in member's email address that is read-only.

How can I generate a selection under a drop down menu that when selected will pre fill a form with row/record data from my database.

I've been at it for weeks now and can not seem to find any sense of direction on how to achieve this.  Can't really find any tutorials site, video, sample code or anything close on how to make this possible thanks for your help in advance.

**FORM**

```
</header>

<body>

<form action="/demoform/contact_form.php" class="well" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" novalidate="">

<big>LOAD PAST ORDERS:</big>
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
 <option value="xxx">SAMPLE SELECTION</option>
</select>

</br>

<input type="text" required id="mile" name="mile" placeholder="Miles"/>

</br>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text" value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>

</br>

<input id="name" name="itemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME 1" required="" type="text" />

</br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />


<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>


</body>


</html>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

if (isset($_POST['itemname'])){
    $itm = $_POST['itemname'];
}
else {
  $itm = '';
}



if($_POST['mile']){
    $mi = $_POST['mile'];
}else{
    echo "Miles not received";
    exit;
}



if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}else{
    echo "email not received";
    exit;
}




$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, mile, email) 
        VALUES ('$itm', '$mi', '$email')";

if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

**PIC**

http://oi57.tinypic.com/2iubb4j.jpg

Comment: use <datalist> and <input list=dataListID>

Answer (score 0):

I Think This Will Help You.......

```
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
<?php
$query='select * from tablename';
$res=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
 <option value="<?php echo $row['feildname']; ?>"><?php echo $row['feildname']; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```